# Why different instances of Docker image running on same port

Tags: containers

I created a Asp.net application with Docker (windows) support. I created image (eshoplegacymvc:dev) of it  and run it using command

```
docker run eshoplegacymvc:dev
```

I ran above command multiple times, what I understand is that when we run it, website will be available.

**Queries :**

1) So if I run it 5 times, does it mean 5 instance of those websites are running?

2) If yes, then why port number of all is same? And how can I access those websites from local machine, I am not able to do that.

See below screenshot which shows all process running by using docker command

```
Docker ps
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While running the docker command, you have not specified the port mapping. The ports 80/tcp shown is of container tcp port and not host port.

1) Yes, you are running 5 instance of websites.
2) To access website, you need to provide different port mapping for each container instance.

Example:

```
docker run -p 8081:80 eshoplegacymvc:dev
docker run -p 8082:80 eshoplegacymvc:dev
docker run -p 8083:80 eshoplegacymvc:dev
docker run -p 8084:80 eshoplegacymvc:dev
docker run -p 8085:80 eshoplegacymvc:dev
```

In the above examples, tcp port 80 of the container binds to TCP port 8081/8082/8083/8084/8085 of the host machine.

You can access the site using http://localhost:8081/

For more information on port binding you can check [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/)

Comment: Thanks I understood. When I use OPTION -d control returns whereas it doesn't when I don't why is it that? And does it make any difference how I access the container or its use?

Comment: @Sujit -d is for -detach mode Run container in background and print container ID

Comment: @HarshManvar does it have any difference on container use or utility if we use -D or not

Comment: suppose you are using laravel and your last command on container is php artisan sever....so container output will localhost running on port : 8080......you can check output of container now if you press control + c container get terminated

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes you are running 5 website instances
2. you forget to setup port mapping

`docker run -p 8888:80 eshoplegacymvc:dev` 
using this command you can map ports

your website will be running on localhost:8888

for 5 container you can do it 5 time with -p 8777:80 with different ports 8888:80 ; 8999:80 
which addressing to container port 80 and exposing it over 8777

Comment: So if 5 instances of a website are running on the same port of host (say with port mapping 8777:80) , then which container instance will be called? All or any of them randomly?

Comment: it will be on port base n as in uper answer ...8777:80 ; 8888:80 ; 8999:80

Comment: you can check about detach mode here https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/virtualization_and_cloud/9781786469908/7/ch07lvl1sec33/runtime-modes-detached-and-foreground

Comment: Yes, I am using windows container.